# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Pop' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, browser

Where do i add property for this popup iframe? i am trying to unblind click from a jquery managed section where i have a popup iframe triggered by shadowbox.js(plugin java).

```
// social buttons
    $('.book4b a').unbind('click').click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_new');
        return false;});
// Shadowbox popup
$('.wr a').unbind('click').click(function() {
    top.iframes['Pop'].location.href =window.open($(this).attr('href'));
return false;});
```

Error i get is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Pop' of undefined"

thank you so much!

Comment: Do you have an iframe with the name Pop ?

Comment: @adeneo yes, i do. that's the iframe triggered by shadowbox. 150*400 size. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`top.iframes` is undefined; Try using `top.frames` instead.

From MDN, [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.frames) is the property (i believe) you're looking for. And since `top` is just a reference to the parent `window`, it should have the `frames` property.

Comment: Thanks @Brad Christie it didn't work actually. Error stays: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Comment: well, you realize it returns the `contentWindow` of that frame (and not the iframe DOM element), so setting the `.location` is probably not what you want. Instead, you want `document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = '...';` which would make the iframe navigate.